# how to select data from multiple rows in php if one element is common

Tags: php, html, mysql

My table structure is in the link below in image

http://appricart.com/test/ftblstr.png

php code is:

```
<?php
include 'config.php';
include 'head.php';
$mid = $_POST['myuid'];
$tf = mysql_query("select f.fuid, f.myuid, u.username as writer, u.avatar from friends as f, users as u where f.myuid='$mid' or f.fuid='$mid' and u.id='$reqid'");
$tfc = mysql_num_rows($tf);
echo "<div style='background: #e9e9e9'>Friends ($tfc)</div>";
while ($frns = mysql_fetch_array($tf))
{
?>
<?php echo $frns['writer']; ?><br/>
<?php
}

?>
```

Here I want values for `u.id` as if the value of `$mid` is 4 then I want its other row value like 1 or 6. let i explain if value of `myuid` is 4 then i want `u.id=1` or if value of `fuid` is 4 I want `u.id=6`
Thanks in advance..anybody can help me..

Comment: what this condition do? and u.id='$reqid', also use inner join syntax that we can see the relations between tables

Comment: soory i forget to tell that i want to create a variable named $reqid which returns values for u.id when value of myuid is 4 then it return u.id=1 or if value of fuid is 4 then it return  u.id=6

Comment: here it is basic code appricart.com/test/profile.php?id=6
then m using <?php 
$uid = $_GET['id']; ?>
<form><input type="hidden" name="myuid" value="<?php echo $uid; ?>"/>
<input type="submit" value="Friends"/>
</form>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP:

```
$reqid = $mid == 4 ? 1 : ($fuid == 4 ? 6 : 0); // naturally 0 can be whatever else when both conditions aren't met
```

SQL:

```
select f.fuid, f.myuid, u.username as writer, u.avatar
from friends as f, users as u
where f.myuid='$mid' or f.fuid='$mid' and u.id='$reqid'
```

Comment: Sure, the above example shows you a ternary condition: ```$var = (condition ? value_if_true : value_if_false);``` you can put whatever you want and compare however you want. I just nested the conditions to produce an "else" case

Comment: <?php
include 'config.php';
include 'head.php';
$mid = $_POST['myuid'];
$reqid = $mid == $fuid ? 1 : ($fuid == 4 ? 6 : 0);
$tf = mysql_query("select f.fuid, f.myuid, u.username as writer, u.avatar from friends as f, users as u where f.myuid='$mid' or f.fuid='$mid' and u.id='$reqid'");
$tfc = mysql_num_rows($tf);
echo "<div style='background: #e9e9e9'>Friends ($tfc)</div>";
while ($frns = mysql_fetch_array($tf))
{
?>
<?php echo $frns['writer']; ?><br/>
<?php
}
?>

Comment: i dont understand what u actually say plz check this picture first then i hope u understand what i actually want. http://appricart.com/test/ftblstr.png

Comment: i want values of 4 6 etc acording to database.

Comment: As long as you hold the db values in the variables, this should work. remember, `$var = (if ? then : else)`
You might want to consider altering your query to have an if in itself, if it's MySQL you can use `IF()` or `CASE`